# How to Install OpenWrt on Hyper-V?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, openwrt

Are there any clear instructions on how to install OpenWrt on Windows Hyper-V virtual machine?

Answer (score 1):

1. Enable Hyper-V
2. In host PowerShell create OpenWrt virtual disk

```
New-VHD E:\VM\OpenWrt.vhdx -SizeBytes 128MB
```

3. In host PowerShell Attach OpenWrt Virtual Diks to all WSL distributions

```
wsl --mount E:\VM\OpenWrt.vhdx --vhd --bare --name OpenWrt
```

4. In a WSL distribution use lsblk to find the device name with the size of 128MB

```
lsblk -o vendor,model,name,mountpoint,fstype,size,fsuse%,state,label,uuid,pttype
```

5. In a WSL distribution copy OpenWrt image to its virtual disk identified in prior step

```
dd if=openwrt-22.03.5-x86-64-generic-ext4-combined.img of=/dev/sdc bs=1MB
```

6. In host PowerShell detach OpenWrt Virtual Diks from all WSL distributions

```
wsl.exe --unmount \\?\E:\VM\OpenWrt.vhdx
```

7. In host PowerShell create an External Virtual Switch for LAN interface

```
New-VMSwitch -Name "External Switch" -NetAdapterName eth0
```

8. In host PowerShell create OpenWrt Virtual Machine

```
New-VM OpenWrt -MemoryStartupBytes 512MB -SwitchName "External Switch" -VHDPath E:\VM\OpenWrt.vhdx

Add-VMNetworkAdapter OpenWrt -SwitchName "Default Switch"
```

9. In host PowerShell start OpenWrt Virtual Machine

```
Start-VM OpenWrt
```

10. In host PowerShell connect to OpenWrt Virtual Machine

```
vmconnect localhost OpenWrt
```

11. In OpenWrt VM adjust /etc/config/network:

```
config interface 'wan'
    option device 'eth0'
    option proto 'static'
    list ipaddr '192.168.0.10/24'
    list dns '192.168.0.1'
    option gateway '192.168.0.1'

config device
    option type 'bridge'
    option name 'br-lan'
    list ports 'eth1'

config interface 'lan'
    option device 'br-lan'
    option proto 'dhcp'

config interface 'lan2'
    option proto 'static'
    option device '@lan'
    list ipaddr '192.168.4.1/24'
```

12. In OpenWrt VM Restart networking

```
service network restart
```

13. In OpenWrt VM add firewall rules to /etc/config/firewall:

```
config rule
    option  name        'Allow-HTTP'
    option  src         'wan'
    option  proto       'tcp'
    option  dest_port   '80'
    option  target      'ACCEPT'

config  rule
    option  name        'Allow-SSH'
    option  src         'wan'
    option  proto       'tcp'
    option  dest_port   '22'
    option  target      'ACCEPT'
```

14. In OpenWrt VM apply firewall rules

```
service firewall reload
```

15. In host PowerShell Identify "Ethernet adapter vEthernet (Default Switch)" IP Adreess

```
ipconfig /all
```

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.23.160.1(Preferred)
```

16. In host PowerShell add the route to OpenWrt LAN via "Default Switch"

```
route add 192.168.4.0 mask 255.255.255.0 172.23.160.1 metric 3
```

NOTE: making route persistent maybe tricky becuase "Deafault Swith" IP usually changes on reboot

17. In host connect to the configured addressed via a browser to

```
192.168.4.0
or
192.168.0.10
```